# how to solve a problem with filter method in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

How to correct this error and make the code work, the problem with the data filter in redux? I reviewed a lot of material on this topic, but did not find a solution to get the code to work, I would be very grateful for the help. Understanding that the problem may be in reducers, but I could not clearly understand how to correct the error. The key point is to display a list of customers on the left, enter with a filter and click on the user with detailed information on the right.

Here is my example code more detailed -> https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-rgb-7nl0h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your code, your problem is not with filter. The error says that it `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`, it means that `state.allPeople` is undefined. I checked out your reducers and noticed you have no reducers! Write a reducer for `allPeople` and then you'll be ok!

Answer (score 0):

here's a working demo https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-resonance-i71ey. 
I just added -:

`testStore: state.allPeople && state.allPeople.filter(user => isMatch(user, state.filterPeople)) || []`

in `index.js` line no. 122.

Also your `allUsers` and `filterUsers` files are empty.

It will work once we add proper reducer into it.

Comment: Yes, that was my first question and I incorrectly uploaded the files into the codesandbox) Sorry for this ridiculous mistake. ..) I fixed the truth, the filter still does not work correctly